# Swift3 error : Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, anyobject

So, I'm trying to update my toDo list app to swift 3 / iOS 10, but I came across this error when updating. I have looked up the internet and StackOverflow and found that someone else also sort of had this problem, but the solution there, didn't help for me.
This is just one file, that takes care of inserting into Core Data.

This is the code for that file :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager()

struct task {
    var name = "not defined"
    var desc = "not defined"
}

class TaskManager: NSObject {
  var tasks = [task]()
  var persistenceHelper: PersistenceHelper = PersistenceHelper()

  override init(){

    let tempTasks:NSArray = persistenceHelper.list(entity: "Task")
    for res:AnyObject in tempTasks{
        tasks.append(task(name:res.valueForKey("name")as! String,desc:res.valueForKey("desc") as! String))
    }
  }


  func addTask(name:String, desc: String){

    var dicTask: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary<String,String>()
    dicTask["name"] = name
    dicTask["desc"] = desc

    if(persistenceHelper.save(entity: "Task", parameters: dicTask)){
        tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc))
    }
  }

  func removeTask(index:Int){
    let value:String = tasks[index].name 

    if(persistenceHelper.remove(entity: "Task", key: "name", value: value)){
        tasks.remove(at: index)
    }
  }

}
```

So it gives an error on line 18 which go's like this :

> > Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Can anyone help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: It is very rare that you should be forcing `NSArray` like this, and even less likely that you should be forcing `AnyObject` this way. Start by removing those types and let the system perform type inference for you. If you still have trouble, please reduce this to an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/mcve). As you've written your question, it includes a lot of extraneous code (addTask, removeTask) and is missing critical code (the definition of persistenceHelper.list).

Comment: @RobNapier It just give's lot of other error's like "No 'value' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'String'". Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: As noted, please reduce to an MCVE so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks for telling, although your link doesn't work :/ Thanks anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please Update row 18 like this. I hope this will work for you.

```
  for res:AnyObject in tempTasks as [AnyObject]
```